# ng-show isArray expression

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I would like to render `select` tag only if model field is array. I have this code:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="showCrtl">
        <button class="" ng-click="showCon()">Button1</button>   
        <select ng-show="isArray(tabObj.foo)" ng-model="tabObj.foo" ng-options="x for x in tabObj.foo"></select>
        <span ng-if="!isArray(tabObj.foo)">{{tabObj.foo}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function showCrtl($scope){
    $scope.showCon=function(){
        $scope.tabObj={'foo':['AA','BB']};
        alert("is field is Array? "+Array.isArray($scope.tabObj.foo));
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8Yz7S/722/

As you see, after click button I get only `span` with `tabObj.foo` as text.
How to get `select` tag?

---

If I change `tabObj.foo` value to simple string (`'abc'`) and use `ng-show="tabObj.foo.length > 0"` check I always get `select` tag (dont see `span`) - see http://jsfiddle.net/8Yz7S/726/

Comment: `isArray(tabObj.foo)` isn't calling anything, aren't you missing `$scope.isArray = function(arr){return Array.isArray(arr);}` in the controller?

Comment: @Aleksey - So I can't use `Array.isArray()` function in `ng-show` inside ? (like here http://jsfiddle.net/8Yz7S/754/)

Comment: most `ng-` attributes assume  your functions/variables are bounded to `$scope`, but `$scope.isArray` or `$scope.Array.isArray` are not available in the controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ng-show="isArray(tabObj.foo)"` is not working like this in html directly . You can create one more variable and check its value.

```js
function showCrtl($scope){
$scope.test=false;
    $scope.showCon=function(){
           $scope.tabObj={'foo':['AA','BB']};
           $scope.test=Array.isArray($scope.tabObj.foo);
           alert("is field is Array? "+$scope.test);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="showCrtl">
            <button class="" ng-click="showCon()">Button1</button>   
            <select ng-if="test" ng-model="tabObj.foo" ng-options="x for x in tabObj.foo">
            </select>
            <span ng-if="!test">{{tabObj.foo}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the updated jsfiddle you have to define isArray

http://jsfiddle.net/8Yz7S/732/

```
function showCrtl($scope){
    $scope.showCon=function(){
        $scope.tabObj={'foo':['AA','BB']};
        $scope.isArray = angular.isArray;
        alert("is field is Array? "+Array.isArray($scope.tabObj.foo));
    }
}
```

Comment: So I can't use `angular.isArray` function in `ng-show` inside ? (like here http://jsfiddle.net/8Yz7S/749/)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you. Thank you.

```js
function showCrtl($scope){
$scope.isArrayCheck = angular.isArray;
    $scope.showCon=function(){
        $scope.tabObj={'foo':['AA','BB']};  
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="showCrtl">
            <button class="" ng-click="showCon()">Button1</button>   
            <select ng-show="isArrayCheck(tabObj.foo)" ng-model="tabObj.foo" ng-options="x for x in tabObj.foo">
           
            </select>
            <span ng-if="!isArray(tabObj.foo)">{{tabObj.foo}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```